# Consumer failed to start in 60000 milliseconds; does the task executor have enough threads to support the container concurrency?

Tags: concurrency, amqp, consumer

logger error:

> Consumer failed to start in 60000 milliseconds; does the task executor
>   have enough threads to support the container concurrency?

How can I resolve it?

Thanks a lot.

I attempt to change my config like this:

@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfig {

```
private final SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory;

private final RabbitTemplate mqTemplate;

@Autowired
public RabbitMQConfig(SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory,
                      RabbitTemplate mqTemplate) {
    this.simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory = simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory;
    this.mqTemplate = mqTemplate;
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
    simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory.setTaskExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
    simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory.setContainerConfigurer(c -> {
        c.setAutoDeclare(false);
        c.setConsumerStartTimeout(100000L);

    });
    mqTemplate.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
}

@Bean
public Queue dlQueue() {
    return new Queue(RabbitMQConstant.DEAD_LETTER_Q, true, false, false);
}

@Bean
public TopicExchange dlExchange() {
    return new TopicExchange(RabbitMQConstant.DEAD_LETTER_EXCHANGE, true, false);
}

@Bean
public Binding dlxBinding() {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(dlQueue()).to(dlExchange()).with(RabbitMQConstant.ROUTE_KEY);
}
```

}

bug the log also exist and the spring boot start slow.

2020-02-14 12:29:14.861 [main] ERROR org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer [,,,,] hia-api - Consumer failed to start in 100000 milliseconds; does the task executor have enough threads to support the container concurrency?
2020-02-14 12:30:54.870 [main] ERROR org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer [,,,,] hia-api - Consumer failed to start in 100000 milliseconds; does the task executor have enough threads to support the container concurrency?
2020-02-14 12:32:34.872 [main] ERROR org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer [,,,,] hia-api - Consumer failed to start in 100000 milliseconds; does the task executor have enough threads to support the container concurrency?
2020-02-14 12:34:14.873 [main] ERROR org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer [,,,,] hia-api - Consumer failed to start in 100000 milliseconds; does the task executor have enough threads to support the container concurrency?
2020-02-14 12:35:54.877 [main] ERROR org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer [,,,,] hia-api - Consumer failed to start in 100000 milliseconds; does the task executor have enough threads to support the container concurrency?

Comment: spring boot app

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java#L1143

Comment: thank you for your answer, I see your link is the source of amqp, but through this source code , I try to reset the task executor and  modify ConsumerStartTimeout， but it does't work, when spring boot start up, the log also exist like this :

Comment: 2020-02-14 12:29:14.861 [main] ERROR org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer [,,,,] hia-api - Consumer failed to start in 100000 milliseconds; does the task executor have enough threads to support the container concurrency?

Answer (score 1):

```
Consumer failed to start in 60000 milliseconds; does the task executor have enough threads to support the container concurrency?
```

One of the root causes is that the MQ server is unavailable. Check that the MQ server is running and accessible

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need to check the "Core Pool Size" for your taskExecutor class. Setting this number to a higher value will probably solve your problem. Keep in mind that this will increase the number of threads to be kept in the pool.